# Trying to bring up new button whenever prompt is answered correctly

Tags: javascript, html, prompt

So right now I'm trying to program what would essentially be a simple game where the user is given a riddle and when they give the correct answer they are allowed to move on to the next riddle.
Right now i can bring up a prompt that you then answer the question for which leads to more text, and i can hypothetically add a button in ... but then along with the button comes all of the coding surrounding it also? 
Is there anyway to fix this? Or is there a better coding alternative for what i'm trying to do? I kind of wish I knew how to use forms instead of prompts and buttons but from what i've tried to find i can't seem to see any way of doing that.

Here's what i've written so far (sorry i haven't posted on this website before, i'm actually just pretty desperate now) (Ps. Im aware that i'm very bad at coding):

```
<p>Click the button!.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>


<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

function nextButton()
{{
<button onclick="nextButton()">Next question!</button>
}

var y;
var name=prompt("What are bunnies?");

if (name!="fluffy")
{
 y= name + " " + "is" + " " + "wrong!";
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=y;
 }
 else
 {
 y="correct!";
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=y;
 }
 }

 function myFunction()
 {
 var x;

 var name=prompt("what is cute a fluffy and adorable?");

 if (name!="a bunny")
  {
  x= name + " " + "is" + " " + "wrong!";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
  }
  else
  {

  x="correct!" + nextButton ;
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe change your nextButton function to the following:

```
function nextButton()
{
   return "<button onclick='nextButton()'>Next question!</button>";
}
```

and see if that works.

EDIT: Also change

```
x="correct!" + nextButton ;
```

To:

```
x="correct!" + nextButton() ;
```

That should fix the script problem.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! The button shows up fine now :) though it seems to not work when i press it?

Comment: Maybe it is working, but remember it is just calling the same function, so it display itself again. Have an alert() in there and see if it's showing the alert when you click the button.

Answer (score 1):

You could try an on load hide function and then implement an else if statement to if answer a is selected show button else msbox "Please try again" ? Sorry; I'm taking what I've learned from C# and C++ and seeing if it might be helpful for you in Javascript, but I'm not 100% sure it will be. (So if you could let me know that would be great too. :) )